# ¿Como capturar variable JSON de javascript dentro de un controlador en Laravel al enviar formulario?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Estoy utilizando Vue Js:

```
var VueJS = new Vue({
        el: '#contenido',
        mounted: function(){

        },
        data: {
            listaModulosSeleccionados: [],
            listaModulos: <?php echo json_encode($listaModulos); ?>
        }
    });
```

Y quisiera capturar la variable `listaModulosSeleccionados` en el metodo `store` del controlador al enviar el formulario.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    /*$usuario = new tbl_usuario();
    $usuario->usuario_id = $request['txtIdentidad'];
    $usuario->usuario_nombres = $request['txtNombres'];
    $usuario->usuario_apellidos = $request['txtApellidos'];
    $usuario->usuario_direccion = $request['txtDireccion'];
    $usuario->usuario_telefono = $request['txtTelefono'];
    $usuario->usuario_correo = $request['txtCorreo'];
    $usuario->usuario_fechaNacimiento = $request['txtFechaDeNacimiento'];
    $usuario->tipo_id = $request['cmbTipo'];
    $usuario->estadoCivil_id = $request['cmbEstadoCivil'];
    $usuario->usuario_user = $request['txtUsuario'];
    $usuario->usuario_clave = $request['txtClave'];
    $usuario->usuario_estado = $request['cbEstado']?'1':'0';

    $usuario->save();
    return redirect('Usuarios/create');*/

    Justamente aqui quisiera obtener esa variable la cual es un arreglo JSON y cargarlo en una variable PHP

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes crear un input hidden dentro del formulario y asignarle como value el valor de la propiedad en vue, como es un objeto requerirás usar stringify para pasarlo a string, para ello debes usar una computed property para obtener siempre el valor en tiempo real.

te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>VueJs Introduction</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = 
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
     <input type="text" :value="mypropstringify"/>
  </div>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
     var vue_det = new Vue({
        el: '#intro',
        data: {
           myprop: [
                {"hola":"chao"},
                {"pan": "queso"}
               ]
        },
        computed:{
            mypropstringify(){
                return JSON.stringify(this.myprop)
            }
        }
     });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He compilado el código en una pagina que me he encontrado por internet por si gustas probarlo de forma facil: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_vuejs_editor.php

Comment: Grazie! con esto logre capturar la variable :,v  Estuve un dia buscando solucion.